# FieldSet accessible in Lightning Flows?

Tags: visual-flows, fieldsets, flowscreen

I want to create Custom Contact screen with selected fields on Account record. Since record type selection is not available on quick action I was trying to create a lightning flows where I want to show record type selection screen and based on record type selection I want to show different different fields which is applicable for selected record types.
I can add those fields manually in screen but I am looking for generic solution such as Field sets.

In Lightning Component, we can make a server call and fetch field sets and display fields from fieldsets on the page. I want to know if this is possible in flows. If I want to add/remove fields, I dont want to edit my flows everytime.

I dont want coding solution so I want to know if it is possible to do it in flows?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this using Custom Metadata Type.
Check this 'trailhead' link once.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/custom_metadata_types_dec/cmt_create

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).